# Using a formula to specify sheet in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

What I did is pseudocode basically and I just want to specify the sheet using a cell as shown in the picture. What is the proper notation (if there is any)?

(Trying to solve E3 in this example. It should show a number from another sheet, and I just want to make it easy to copy/paste down column E by referencing to the sheets using the strings in column A)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function to do that, for example :

```
=INDIRECT(A3 & "!B4")
```

You may need to wrap sheet name with quotes if it contains special character(s) :

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A3 & "'!B4")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at indirect, but Google's explanation is too vague to people who don't actually know what it does.